# How can I leave only needed parts of code from bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, optimization, webpack

[The screenshoot of coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBm7Q.png)

So, i have an project that I currently work on it, and now become time to optimize it. Based on "devtool > coverage" , from bootstrap.bundle.min.js is used only 3-4% of code (In screenshot, the first one).
So question is that is there a way to optimize it somehow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would really be a significant optimization?

Comment: Probably not, but anyway i want to know that is possible or not. And if Yes, how?

Comment: have you tried https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ it allows you to choose which styles, components and scripts you want included in your custom bundle

Answer (score 0):

Use `Uglify.js` or `Terser`, it will remove unused code